# What version of Perl is shipped with the Desktop Version of 11.10?

Tags: perl

Kindly let me know if Perl Version 5.12.4 is included in the desktop version of Ubuntu 11.10 or does it have to be seperately downloaded? I have been to packages.ubuntu.com and found that Perl Version 5.12.4 is available on Ubuntu, but is that the server version or desktop version?

Or does it mean that the package is available, but I have to download it seperately? Kindly let me know. I will be using Ubuntu mainly as my personal desktop system as well as doing some scripting on Perl and Python.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 11.10 Oneiric comes with Perl 5.12.4, as you can see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/perl).

Answer (score 1):

You are quite correct - 5.12.4 is installed in oneiric (11.10) as per

```
perl -v

This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 4 (v5.12.4) built for i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int
(with 45 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

It is automatically installed with an installation of ubuntu.

Comment: Respected Folks, Thank you for your answers. This is where Ubuntu really scores over other Desktop Versions.I guess even Python will be pre added and so will other stuff like GCC etc.....I'll find out...over now to the Ubuntu site to download and try it out...Cant wait to take off the big Virus called Win7 off my laptop :D

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, there is a plugin for firefox that allows you to search ubuntu packages

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/search-ubuntu-packages/