# How can I use perl 5.12 in 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, perl

How can I use perl 5.12 in Ubuntu? There is no distribution package on Ubuntu.

I have to use `feature 'unicode_strings';` in my perl code, and this is available from 5.12.
I try to install perl on Ubuntu by `apt-get install perl`, but 5.10 is the latest version.

How can I deal with this? Or is there any code in 5.10 can replace the code `feature 'unicode_strings';`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

When writing your own applications, I recommend installing your own Perl. This was once a major pain, but no more. Nowadays, you can use [perlbrew](https://metacpan.org/module/perlbrew) to build Perl for you.

On Ubuntu, I think you'll need the build-essential package first, if you don't already. After that, you can use the instructions on the perlbrew docs linked above to install it (or use `cpan App::perlbrew`).

Once installed you can run:

```
perlbrew init
perlbrew install perl-5.12.2
perlbrew switch perl-5.12.2
```

Once you do that and make sure Perlbrew's bashrc is loaded into your bashrc, you should be ale to run:

```
perl -v
```

and see that you're running 5.12.

---

The official `perlbrew` website is https://perlbrew.pl and it suggests installing by running

```
wget --no-check-certificate -O - http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
```

Then you will still need to

```
perlbrew install perl-5.12.2
perlbrew switch perl-5.12.2
```

of course. Finally if you have multiple cores (and who doesn't these days) you can run

```
perlbrew install -j N perl-5.12.2
```

where `N` is the number of jobs requested, often the number of cores you have plus one. I use `-j 5` on my quad-core and `-j 3` on my dual-core netbook.

Comment: following the comments on alpera's answer, I also want to state that using this method, the new Perl is installed in your own userspace. Repeat it does not affect the system Perl at all. You have your own copy of whichever Perl version(s) you want. This is the best choice for you.

Comment: I need run `perlbrew --notest install perl-5.22.1` to pass 'test_harness' failed

Comment: if want script support perlbrew, it need use !/usr/bin/env perl instead !/usr/bin/perl

Answer (score 2):

Anyway you can easily download last Perl distribution (5.16 or 5.14) and install it:

**1. Install Perl**

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/R/RJ/RJBS/perl-5.16.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf perl-5.16.0.tar.gz
cd perl-5.16.0
./Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/usr/local
make
make test
sudo make install
```

then add:

```
export PATH=$HOME/usr/local/bin/:$PATH
```

as result you will get:

```
 $ perl -v 
 $ perl 5.16
```

Old perl version is still locate here: `/usr/bin/perl`

new Perl version will be there: `/usr/local/bin/perl`

**2. Work with CPAN modules**

I suggest you install cpanminus (*[cpanm](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.5017/bin/cpanm)*) for easy manage CPAN modules for new version of Perl.

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.5017.tar.gz
tar -xzf App-cpanminus-1.5017.tar.gz
cd App-cpanminus-1.5017
perl Make.pl
make
make test
sudo make install
```

After that you can install CPAN modules for your new version of Perl.

Answer (score 0):

you may consider downloading .deb package and installing it from dpkg.
the command for a .deb package:

```
dpkg -i my.deb
```

you may find the deb file for perl 5.12 in here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/perl/5.12.3-6ubuntu4/+build/2483691
named: perl_5.12.3-6ubuntu4_i386.deb (3.4 MiB)

it will probably want another package and another one want another one..... recursively :)
but it's always possible to install like this.

Comment: But it seems like a 32bit version right? I have a 64bit ubuntu.

Comment: also you may update your sources for apt and hopefully you'll find a newer version of perl. for example i just looked for a debian mirror (ftp://ftp.linux.org.tr/debian/pool/main/p/perl/) and see perl 5.14 there

Comment: you can find an 64bit version too, here it is: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/71084438/perl_5.12.3-6ubuntu3_amd64.deb ..by the way i dont like installing packages manually so use this process with your own risk, i'm not responsible if a critical machine breaks down. :)

Comment: Yes, a breakdown can be horrible...

Comment: Because I am not using my own server now, too terrible.

Comment: then nevermind what i said, experimental things may cause headache :)

Comment: Yes. I just want to use perl to address a text file so I don't want to make it too complex to configure other things. But this has made me painful...